# Unable to forward port 80 to 8080 using NGINX

Tags: nginx, portforwarding

I have been trying to set up NGINX for the first time and I need to enable port forwarding from 80 to 8080 for my website. However, after many attempts I have obtained nothing. Here is my latest attempt:

I followed the steps here accordingly: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-virtual-hosts-server-blocks-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts--3

The difference is the fact that my nginx.conf file contains:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name myWebsiteName;

    access_log /home/path_to_site/access.log;
    error_log /home/path_to_site/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Is this the right file content? Am I using the wrong tutorial?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The example you provided contains some mistakes:

- 0.0.0.0 is not the same as localhost, you probably want this IP-address to be 127.0.0.1
- 8082 does not match the port you want to forward to (which, I believe, is 8080).

A fixed example could be:

```
server{
   listen 80;
   server_name myWebsiteName;

   access_log /home/path_to_site/access.log;
   error_log /home/path_to_site/error.log;

   location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }
}
```

In this example all incoming requests on port 80 will be proxied to port 8080 on this host.

Despite this being possible, is this really the solution you are looking for? Is it possible to change the listening port for the application that you are proxying to?

Comment: Hey, thank you for responding. I have pasted the unmodified example, my code actually looks like the one you have posted, sorry about the confusion. Is there another way of doing this? Yes, changing the port for the application should be possible.

Comment: If you change the port of the application that is running on port 8080 to listen on port 80, it seems to me like the need for nginx is no longer there. If this is not the case, could you explain why you want nginx to be in between the application on port 8080 and web clients? Or is the only reason to be able to port forward?